Duplicating existing sheet based on conditional values in the list
I want to spit out the new tabs, whose names will be based on the cell values. However, the majority of the list includes empty cells, which I would like to have skipped.

The list is marked yellow. Once the function encounters the name I want to duplicate the existing sheet called "-X-" with the name inherited from the value represented on the list of cells.

My code so far looks like this:
Sub Namedsheetsadding()

Dim bws As Worksheet, tws As Worksheet

Dim i As Long, xCount As Long
Dim Nodenames As Variant
Dim NodeSampleName As Variant
Dim NodeName As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long



Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-X-")
Set bws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L3-SHEF-X-BE03")
lr = bws.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Ro

For Each cell In NodeRange
If Value <> "" Then
Set NodeName = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("-X-"))
End If
Next

End Sub

How could I duplicate the sheets based on the values in the list
UPDATE:
By applying this solution:
copy sheet and cell value based on list and rename as per list with excel vba code
I could copy the sheets, but still, empty values are taken.
When I applied the if condition, I see the code executed but without any results
Sub Namedsheetsadding()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim bws As Worksheet: Set bws = wb.Worksheets("L3-SHEF-X-BE03")

Dim jlRow As Long
jlRow = bws.Cells(bws.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row

Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Worksheets("-X-")

Dim dws As Worksheet

Dim jr As Long

For jr = 5 To jlRow
If Cells(jr, jlRow) <> "" Then
tws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
dws.Name = bws.Cells(jr, "X").Value
End If

Next jr

End Sub


Try a loop like this:
For jr = 5 To jlRow
    If bws.Cells(jr, "X").Value <> "" Then
        tws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        dws.Name = bws.Cells(jr, "X").Value
    End If
Next jr


Copy Sheet As Many Times As There Are Non-Blanks in Column
1st Time

2nd Time

Sub Namedsheetsadding()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("L3-SHEF-X-BE03")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Sheets("-X-")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim nws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet, sr As Long, dName As String
    Dim WasAnySheetRenamed As Boolean
    
    For sr = 5 To slRow
        dName = CStr(sws.Cells(sr, "X").Value)
        If Len(dName) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
                Set nws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If nws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet doesn't exist
                If dws Is Nothing Then
                    cws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                    Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                End If
                On Error Resume Next
                    dws.Name = dName
                On Error GoTo 0
                If dws.Name = dName Then ' was renamed
                    WasAnySheetRenamed = True
                    ' This is where to place code for each newly added sheet.
                
                    Set dws = Nothing
                    Debug.Print "Created """ & dName & """."
                Else ' was not renamed
                    ' Do what? E.g.:
                    Debug.Print "Invalid sheet name """ & dName & """!"
                End If
            Else ' worksheet exists
                Set nws = Nothing
                ' Do what? E.g.:
                Debug.Print "Exists """ & dName & """!"
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    'wb.Activate
    'sws.Activate
    
    If Not dws Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If WasAnySheetRenamed Then
        MsgBox "Worksheets created.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No worksheets created!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

Results in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G)
Created "Shef-x-1".
Created "Shef-x-2".
Invalid sheet name "History"!
Created "Shef-x-4".
Exists "Shef-x-1"!
Exists "Shef-x-2"!
Invalid sheet name "History"!
Exists "Shef-x-4"!

